# Creating circular buffers around a point in QGIS with Python

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-3, buffer

I have a script that creates a square buffer of 1 degree around a point in QGIS, through the python console but I am unable to find a way to create circular buffers instead. Also, would it be possible to add to the script to add multiple buffers around the same point of different distances, as I currently have 1 degree but would like 5 degrees, 10 degrees... etc. The script I have currently written:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

feats = [ feat for feat in layer.getFeatures() ]

epsg = layer.crs().postgisSrid()

uri = "Polygon?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer&field=x:real&field=y:real&field=point_id:integer""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,
                           'circular_buffer',
                           'memory')

prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
    point = feat.geometry().asPoint()
    new_feat = QgsFeature()
    new_feat.setAttributes([i, point[0], point[1], feat.id()])
    tmp_feat = feat.geometry().buffer(1, -1).boundingBox().asWktPolygon()
    new_feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromWkt(tmp_feat))
    prov.addFeatures([new_feat])

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

Comment: Have you tried to use: tmp_feat = feat.geometry().buffer(1, -1).asWktPolygon() instead. without the boundingbox function it should return a circular buffer

Comment: A one degree buffer is an odd requirement, since degrees are angular measurements which measure wildly differing distances depending on latitude.  A sixty nautical mile buffer would be slightly oblate over the Equator, and more and more egg-shaped as you increased latitude, so if you're doing a buffer in decimal degrees and see a circle, it's pretty much always wrong.

Comment: @eurojam Unfortunately after removing the bounding box function, it comes up with an error - AttributeError: 'QgsGeometry' object has no attribute 'asWktPolygon'. Any ideas?

Comment: @Vince I have tried to get a different CRS so that it would be in metres or another measurement other than degrees but every time I change the projection, I either can not see the geojson file or other files within my project

Comment: GeoJSON is restricted to WGS84 (4326), so that's nearly a different issue (GeoJSON isn't mentioned anywhere in the question). Note that projection "change" usually applies to clobbering the existing CRS, when "reprojection" is usually the goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following, which will work anyway. Since the tmp_feat is from type geometry you can pass it directly to new_feat.setGeometry(tmp_feat)

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
feats = [ feat for feat in layer.getFeatures() ]
epsg = layer.crs().postgisSrid()
uri = "Polygon?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer&field=x:real&    field=y:real&field=point_id:integer""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,
                       'circular_buffer',
                       'memory')
prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
    point = feat.geometry().asPoint()
    new_feat = QgsFeature()
    new_feat.setAttributes([i, point[0], point[1], feat.id()])
    tmp_feat = feat.geometry().buffer(1, -1)
    new_feat.setGeometry(tmp_feat)
    prov.addFeatures([new_feat])

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now!

Comment: Do you know how I would be able to change the buffer opacity to 50% and to also change the color of the buffer to red too? Thanks

Comment: it is something like: sym =mem_layer.renderer().symbol() sym.setColor(QColor("red")) sym.setOpacity(50)